# Losing Exception information with HttpError

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to get a custom errorid (hashed guid) to an HttpError when exceptions are raised through an application.  So a message like "xxxxxx - error" is passed to the client.

We have a custom [ExceptionFilterAttribute](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAAahUKEwilqbCuq4_IAhUBHCwKHYy3Cog&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.web.http.filters.exceptionfilterattribute(v%3Dvs.118).aspx&usg=AFQjCNEuxNmObY_riDIWkWrsXEGnEF3JEw&sig2=EVBObGliTbta568ZyU7D6w) to catch and log exceptions:

```
public class ExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    ...
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        context.Exception.Data.Add("guid", guid);
        _log.WriteEvent(message, context.Exception, guid);
    }
}
```

A custom [MediaTypeFormatter](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAAahUKEwjf_oLiqo_IAhVE8RQKHWnwAxA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.net.http.formatting.mediatypeformatter(v%3Dvs.118).aspx&usg=AFQjCNH9i_Rp-220Na6N1_f1n71-1yfpqw&sig2=xqP_80GdLgEeAXT-fZGRyg&bvm=bv.103388427,d.bGg) to send this (among other types) as json back to the client:

```
public class DotNetJsonFormatter : MediaTypeFormatter
{
    ...
    public override Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, Stream stream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            if (typeof(Exception).IsAssignableFrom(type)) {
                // write a json string to the stream containing the message and id
            } else if (typeof(HttpError).IsAssignableFrom(type)) {
                // write a json string to the stream containing the message and id
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My problem lies with `HttpError` - all it contains is a dictionary containing the message, type, stack trace etc - I thought setting the data might pull this through (I've checked the HttpError constructor and that's all that's pulled from the exception).

- I can't re-write the application to throw custom exceptions so the id ends up in the message.
- I 'could' using reflection, alter the exception message to contain the id in the filter but it feels hacky.
- Thought about re-throwing a new exception with the id in the message from the filter but this seems to bypass the formatter altogether
- Tried setting the Exception property of the filter to set the underlying exception but it has no effect.

Am I stuck with the [reflection technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11671589/746674)?

Comment: Unless I just bypass the formatter and set the response of the `HttpActionExecutedContext` directly?

Comment: What is the type of `context.Exception`? If it's HttpError then you might have to use the items.add instead of data.add

Comment: @P.K. context.Exception is of type Exception.

Answer (score 0):

I hate answering my own questions but I will anyway.

So one option I didn't consider (too much inside box thinking) was setting the response in the filter rather than letting the formatter handle it.

The updated filter:

```
public class ExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public ExceptionFilter(ILogger log, IClientExceptionFormatter exceptionFormatter)
    {
        ...
        _log = log;
        _exceptionFormatter = exceptionFormatter;
    }

    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        ...
        _log.Error(context.Exception);
        context.Response = new ExceptionJsonResponse(context.Exception, _exceptionFormatter);
    }
    ...
}
```

The `ExceptionJsonResponse` class:

```
public class ExceptionJsonResponse : HttpResponseMessage
{
    public ExceptionJsonResponse(Exception exception, IClientExceptionFormatter formatter)
    {
        ...
        _exception = exception;
        _formatter = formatter;

        Content = CreateContent();
        StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
    }

    private HttpContent CreateContent()
    {
        HttpContent content = new StringContent(_formatter.GetJson(_exception));
        content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(Common.ContentType.ApplicationJson);
        return content;
    }
    ...
}
```

This way bypasses the formatter probably because the response is a HttpResponseMessage.  I can then alter the client message to my hearts content.